# how to achieve temporary page in squid 3?

Tags: linux, proxy, squid

I'm trying to achieve a temporary announcement page for all the client requests, which means this page will disappear after a few seconds and the URL will be back to the original client request. I also tried the url_rewrite_program in perl like below and deny_info (& allow localhost ) acl for this, but both failed. does anybody have a better idea for this? I really need your help. thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @X;
my $url="";

$| = 1;

while (<>)
{
  @X = split;
  $url = $X[0];
  print "302:http://announcement.txt\n";
  sleep 5;
  print "$url\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have squid, so forget about trying to code it yourself and use squid's built-in [splash page](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Portal/Splash) functionality.

This 3.2+ example from the squid page will show the splash page `/etc/squid/splash.html` once per hour (see that page for more examples and full instructions, including examples for squid prior to 3.2):

```
# mind the wrap. this is one line:
external_acl_type splash_page ttl=60 concurrency=100 %SRC /usr/local/sbin/squid/ext_session_acl -t 7200 -b /var/lib/squid/session.db

acl existing_users external splash_page

http_access deny !existing_users

# Deny page to display
deny_info 511:/etc/squid/splash.html existing_users
```

Comment: thanks for your input! It seems that this's only for squid 3.2~, so I have to upgrade all the servers from 3 to 3.2 firstly. This announcement is for the end-using of those servers. all of them will be changed into ProxySG in recent days, sigh! anyway, I don't think I can run away this time :-)